# Separate RMS Server for Exchange 2007?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, exchange-2007, permissions

We are running Exchange 2007 SP2 on Server 2003.  I have already installed the pre-licensing agent on the HUB servers and enabled the transport agents.  I'm also running Windows 7 so there is no need for the pre-licensing agent on the client.  I'm still getting prompted to sign up for a Live ID when I try to send a "Do not forward" email.  I have already installed and enabled these pre-licensing agents.  Do I actually need a separate RMS server to dish out these licenses or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996600(EXCHG.80).aspx), whilst the pre-licencing agent is installed on Exchange, it is just that, an Agent, you still need an RMS server for it be an agent of.

Comment: That is exaclty the answer I was looking for, but was having trouble finding.  Thank you very much.